# Including legacy JS into a Typescript module

Tags: typescript

The business has an old JS file called legacy.js
The goal is to use this file in a new module that’s being written using
 Typescript. We’ll call this the “jumper” module.

Another developer will then pull this module from git and use the module in a project called “jumperdemo” and get the following error:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ../jumper/dist/index.js
>   Module not found: Can't resolve 'Legacy' in '{base path}\jumper\dist'

Simple repo steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/warrick-eosny/jumper.git
cd jumper
npm install
tsc 
cd dist
npm link

cd ..

git clone https://github.com/warrick-eosny/jumpdemo.git
cd jumpdemo
npm install
npm link jumper
yarn start
```

It's becoming clear to me that this pattern does not work well, but what's unclear is what the better pattern would be.

I know I'm not the 1st person to want to include legacy JS into a TS module, so I'm clearly missing something important.

Answer (score 2):

### One Approach for Your Specific Situation

First change your `*.d.ts` file.

- Remove `declare module 'Legacy'` to make a declaration for a `./relative` module.
- Add `export default class...` to match the `legacy.js` export style.
- Move the file to `src/legacy.d.ts` so its path matches the legacy module's path.

Then change your `src/index.ts` file to import and instantiate the default export of the legacy class.

The result will look like this (with some code omitted).

```
// src/index.ts
import legacy from './legacy';
let oldObj = new legacy(); 

// src/legacy.js (unchanged)
export default class OldOldClass {
    runSuperOldLogic(someInput) {
        console.log('really old logic run ' + someInput);
    }
}

// src/legacy.d.ts
export default class OldOldClass {
    runSuperOldLogic(someInput: string): any;
}
```

### Two Alternate Approaches

The TypeScript docs have [an article](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html) on migrating from JavaScript. There are too many approaches to detail all of them. Here are two that might fit your situation: use `allowJs` to consume local JavaScript without types; or, change `legacy.js` to `legacy.ts` and put types inline with the implementation.

### And...

I forked your terrific minimal sample repo and made a PR for it here https://github.com/warrick-eosny/jumper/pull/1/jumper

Comment: mm .. this seemed like it should work, but I merged your pull request and tried it and still run into the same problem.

Comment: Let me know if you want some more help with the merge.